# How to have two different custom error pages in .haccess?

Tags: .htaccess, error-handling, custom-error-pages

### 1.

I have a .haccess file that requires you do be accessing from a certain IP address:

```
<RequireAll>
    Require ip XX.XX.XX.XX.XX YY.YY.YY.YY.YY ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ
</RequireAll>
```

If someone tries to access the website from a IP other then X, Y, or Z then they get an error `403 Forbidden` page. I have customized it using the following:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /.forbidden.php
```

### 2.

If someone tries to access a restricted file in the same directory (even if they are from ip addresses X, Y, or Z) then again they prompted with the **SAME** custom `403 Forbidden` page.

### My Question

How can I have two different custom `403 Forbidden` pages based on why they are forbidden from accessing? In example 1 the forbidden page would `/.wrongip.php` and in example 2 the forbidden page would `/.restricted.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is about the extent of what you are doing then it is fine but if you are going to be doing a lot of redirecting I would consider doing this in PHP, but I digress. You are going to have to use Apache (2.4) module [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to rewrite rules and conditions for the IP restriction portion. I would leave your custom 403 Forbidden as is for handling the other cases of that status code. If you are on shared hosting this module is usually enabled by most hosting providers by default.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111.222.333.444$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /.wrongip.php [L]
```

You will likely avoid confusion if you keep rule rewrites up near the top of your `.htaccess` file. You only need the `RewriteEngine On` line once in your file. `RewriteCond` is one of the conditions for the rule immediately following. You could have multiple conditions mapped to a single rule (using [OR] flag; AND behavior is by default).

In this solution, the `^` character indicates the start of a string. Likewise, `$` indicates the end. So, `^(.*)$` is a wildcard and would match any file accessed on your server. Preceded by a single space separator, the `/.wrongip.php` portion indicates your custom error page to be redirected to. `[L]` is the flag to indicate the Apache server should stop processing other rules once it matches that one. Use this unless you are using multiple rules to construct a single URL, otherwise you may cause yourself a headache.

There is an additional flag, `[R]`, that I would suggest being aware of and trying to use when possible for easier use in maintaining good practice with HTTP response codes. These help with search rankings and I would recommend specifying a 403 response because by default it will throw a 302 error which can negatively effect ranking over time. Changing the rule to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /.wrongip.php [R=403,L]` would cause the Apache server to issue an **HTTP redirect** to the browser (to */.wrongip.php*) and communicate a 403 Forbidden error in the header. Since my example has *all* pages redirecting to */.wrongip.php* for non-whitelisted IPs, most likely even */.wrongip.php* itself, I think in your specific case the `[R]` flag would result in an HTTP redirect loop where they would keep requesting */.wrongip.php*. In this case you should omit the `[R]` flag, this will cause the Apache server to do an **internal redirect**.

Without the `[R]` flag, the client won't have any idea that this redirect went on (hence *internal*), so you should still emulate the error code in the header of your */.wrongip.php* file using PHP.

Comment: I get what your saying...sort of.. but I am unsure what exactly to put in the `.htaccess` file. I tried commenting out the `<RequireAll>` stuff, but kept the custom error page, and then adding the `Rewrite Engine` but it produced two different errors. Internal Error when the IP didn't match and a Document Handler Error when accessing a restricted file. Can you please edit your answer to include exactly what my `.htaccess` file should look like? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can certainly try but you need to share the appropriate snippets of your Apache access logs so we can take a look at exactly how the server is trying to process the requests in question. It could be anything from mod_rewrite not being enabled to a bad path or a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it, but I assume something like

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite>
    ErrorDocument 403 /.restricted.php
    <RequireAll>
        Require ip XX.XX.XX.XX.XX YY.YY.YY.YY.YY ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ
        ErrorDocument 403 /.wrongip.php
    </RequireAll>
</Directory>
```

could do the trick.

Have a look at
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/custom-error.html and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#errordocument for more information on how such configurations work.

Comment: Produces a 500 Internal Server Error